# R - Create subvector iterative

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

I currently have this for-loop which I want to vectorize. It calculates the percentage amount of 6's in a for different subvectors. Starting with a[1:100], a[1:200], ... always in 100's steps.

```
rolls.max <- 100000
a <- sample(1:6, size=rolls.max, replace=TRUE)

sixes.ratio <- c()
for(i in 1:(rolls.max/100)) {
  sixes.count <- table(a[1:(i*100)])[6]
  ratio <- sixes.count/(i*100)
  sixes.ratio <- c(sixes.ratio, ratio)
}
```

I think the most difficult part is to get the count of 6's from a for each subvector. I tried this:

```
rolls.max <- 100000
a <- matrix(sample(1:6, size=rolls.max, replace=TRUE))

subset.creator <- function(x, c) if (c!=0  && c%%100==0) { as.vector(table(x[1:(rolls[c/100])]))[6] }
sixes.count <- mapply(subset.creator, a, col(a))
# Converting the other lines won't be difficult I think
```

Want I wanted to achieve with this is, to create a subvector of a for every 100th call of the function subset.creator. Then create a table and take the sixth column, to get the count of 6's and then extract only the count by using `as.vector()`

But this just gives me rubbish instead of a vector with counts of 6's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a "rolling tally" at every hundredth chunk of your simulated rolls, one way to solve the problem is to create a vector of "stops" that represents your cutoff points, then use `sapply` to perform the calculation (in this case, counting up the 6s) at each stop:

```
rolls.max <- 100000
a <- sample(1:6, size=rolls.max, replace=TRUE)

# a vector of "stops" at every hundredth entry of 'a'
stops <- seq(0, rolls.max, 100)[-1]

# counts of 6s from the first entry in 'a' to the values in 'stops'
count.6 <- sapply(stops, function(x) sum(a[1:x] == 6))

# ...or just as easily, the rolling proportion of 6s
prop.6 <- sapply(stops, function(x) mean(a[1:x] == 6))
```

Comment: Great answer! I'd suggest adding `stops<- stops[-1]` (or the same for `count.6`), since otherwise the first result of the vector are the 6s in `a[1:0]`? Also, maybe change `sum` to `mean` since the question was asking for a proportion.

Comment: Excellent suggestions. Edited.